# Does specifying the number of elements on defining a vector in Racket make the program use less time or memory?

Tags: performance, vector, racket

For example, can this

```
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket/base 

(define vector-of-pleasures #6("eating" "cold showers" "swimming" "running" "pullups" "weighlifting"))
(for ((pleasure vector-of-pleasures)) (displayln pleasure))
```

be more performant because of the optional annotation than this

```
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket/base

(define vector-of-pleasures #("eating" "cold showers" "swimming" "running" "pullups" "weighlifting"))
(for ((pleasure vector-of-pleasures)) (displayln pleasure))
```

?

Methinks it should not matter since in both snippets `vector-of-pleasures` is immutable.
What are, other than performance, possible reasons for annotating the number of the elements of the vector on its definition?

Comment: I have never seen the syntax 6#(1 2 3 4 5 6). in mit-scheme isn't WDF.

Comment: @alinsoar The question is about vectors in Racket. Apologies for not making it clear from the beginning. In response to your comment I added shebangs to the code to make it clear to everyone. What is WDF?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was induced in error by the #scheme tag.

Comment: [well defined form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.  The real use of that syntax is that it lets you write a vector of a bunch of identical things easily: `#6(1)` is a vector of 6 `1`s.

But I think it *could* save space. I can't see why, for instance:

```
(let ((v #2((1 2))))
  (eq? (vector-ref v 0) (vector-ref v 1)))
```

should not be true.  But then this rapidly turns into the question of when similar literals can be folded: can `(eq? '(1 2) '(1 2))` return true for instance?  I don't know what Racket's rules are on that.